# Max function with where clause

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I am using MS access 2007 and this is my original SQL query:

```
SELECT Rates.UNIT, Rates.PROJECT, Rates.[Date_of_CM Memo], Rates.Rates, Rates.REMARKS
FROM Rates, Checks
WHERE (((Rates.UNIT)=[Checks].[Unit_Name]) AND ((Rates.[Date_of_CM Memo])<[Checks].[Reg_Date]));
```

but when I modified this query (below) to display the records for the latest date I get an error saying that I cannot use the max function with the where clause:

```
SELECT Rates.UNIT, Rates.PROJECT, Rates.[Date_of_CM Memo], Rates.Rates, Rates.REMARKS
FROM Rates, Checks
WHERE (((Rates.UNIT)=[Checks].[Unit_Name]) AND (MAX((Rates.[Date_of_CM Memo])<[Checks].[Reg_Date])));
```

Comment: Are you sure all these parentheses in your WHERE clause are necessary ?

Answer (score 2):

You can't just put `MAX` (or any other *aggregate function*) into *WHERE*,
but you can put a *query* like that:

```
SELECT Rates.Unit, 
       Rates.Project, 
       Rates.[Date_of_CM Memo], 
       Rates.Rates, 
       Rates.Remarks
  FROM Rates, 
       Checks
 WHERE (((Rates.Unit) = [Checks].[Unit_Name]) AND 
         ((SELECT MAX (Rates.[Date_of_CM Memo])
             FROM Rates) < [Checks].[Reg_Date])));
```

Comment: Hi, this again shows records for all dates but I only want it to display the latest date...

Comment: Hi, this again shows records for all dates but I only want it to display the record with the latest date... I want the query to compare Reg_date with the Memo_date and only display those records where the reg date is greater than the memo date. In case the reg date is not greater than the memo date then it shud not show any records. If it shows more than 1 record i.e. if there is more than 1 memo date which is previous to the reg date then it should display the record with the latest memo date. I apologize for not explaining this b4... thanks

Comment: @user3125707: if you want to see the latest date only, you'd probably change the comparison: from "<" to "="

Comment: Hi Dmitry changing < to = doesn't display any record

Comment: If you want to see the latest date (time is excluded) while Date_of_CM Memo or/and Reg_Date are in fact have both date and time you should extract date; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368702/selecting-time-ranges-from-date-time-fields-in-access (that extracts time, but extracting date is the similar operation)